# Remove html element / ordering html element problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block, which shows everything in form of a message, that happens on my site. This block contains

```
 `<input class="hide" type="text" id="blockSuccess" value=...>
```

with different values and ids.

I call the ids, to display them in my .ts file in each method, where the message is needed to call, for example:

```
 document.getElementById('blockSuccess').className = 'show';
```

this is a screenshot of the HTML:

[image]

The problem is, that the input texts dont have a strict order and i tried to remove them to make them disappear, and appear again when they are needed, but the problem then is, that they are already removed.
So how  can i remove a html element temporary oder make these input texts order themselves?

Thx

Comment: you can remove them from html but keep the data so it can be rendered again you can use browser storage

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

There it says i can only removeItem(); which removes the stored item only?

Comment: there is a set item as well

Comment: yes but u said i can remove them from html but KEEP the data, how?

Comment: @testtest11 Why you are trying to remove it? you can just play with `display: block` and `display:none` right.?

Comment: yes thats what ive thought too, but these are tons of messages, so do i really have to add for each html element a variable that decides how to display? is there no easier solution

Comment: ok its not as complicated as i thought, thanks for bringing me back on  the track again @mkHun